# Refactor over C# code to implement some kind of Factory Design Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have a Web API App (.NET Core) that is part of my backend. I have implemented the Unit of Work and Repository patterns into a N-Layer 1 Tier Architecture. The way how the Client App and the backend communicate is through sending DTO's (Data Transfer Objects). So, I have different DTO's obviously with a different structure and composition according to what the Repository Method is requesting. This is because at design time I define the type of DTO the Client is expecting, something like this:

```
public EmployeeDto GetEMployeeDto()
{
    public EmployeeDto employee = new EmployeeDto();
    
    .
    .
    .
    // Code to get data from data base and full fill the fields of the DTO.
    .
    .
    .

    return EmployeeDto;

}
```

Where `EmployeeDto` is something like this:

```
public cladd EmployeeDto()
{
     public int Employee Id {get;set;}
     public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
}
```

What I would like to do is remove the instantiating code (`public EmployeeDto employee = new EmployeDto();`) which is tight coupling, and implement some kind of factory pattern where I just call the Factory object, pass the type of DTO I want (because I already know it) and that the Factory returns me the type of DTO I requested and with the DTO state (data).

Just keep on mind that I have several types of DTO's with different structure, so the way how they are fill is different and that the Factory object could be called in different methods and could be requested different DTO's.

Something like:

```
var employee = FactoryDto.GetDto(EmployeDto);
var employeeHistory = FactoryDto.GetDto(EmployeeHistoryDto);
```

With just one line get the whole "package" the DTO itself and the data.

I just need a guidance to which Design Pattern could be the best option and an example, I have read about the Creational Design pattern Factory and the different flavors it has but I have not understood yet how could this achieve.

This is one of the approaches I have:

```
public EmployeeDto GetEmployeeDto(string dtoType)
{
    var factoryDto = new FactoryDto();
    var empDto = factoryDto.GetDto(dtoType);

    return (EmployeeDto)empDto;
}


public class FactoryDto
{
    public object GetDto(string dtoType)
    {
        switch(dtoType)
        {
            case "EmployeeDto":
                {
                    return new EmployeeDto();
                }
            case "EmployeeHistoryDto":
                {
                    return new EmployeeHistoryDto();
                }
            default:
                {
                    return new EmployeeHistoryDto();
                }
        }
            
    }

}
```

But, I do not think this is a correct answer, casting the Dto when returning the Dto and I do not like that Object generic type in the Factory class. Is there a better way to improve this approach using any of the Creational Design Patterns?  Regards!

Comment: What's wrong with `new EmployeeDto()`?

Comment: I personally wouldn't bother, and would just use auto mapper or similar and get a typed result. `Map<type1,type2>(dto)`. Any such solution you propose with a single method and 1 or 0 generic parameters will need to be cast anyway, and will need to check types internally with an if statement or similar.

Comment: how does the Factory know what employee to get the DTO for?

Comment: Hello  @MarkSeemann! Well, according to the Factory Pattern the Client(The method who is instantiating the class) should not create the object, that responsibility should delegate to someone else(In this case a Factory), on this way the creation logic is not exposed to the Client (which does not care) and the factory would return the object that was requested.

Comment: Hello @TheGeneral! To cast the Dto when is returned could be a solution, something like first assign the result into a general Object type and later on just cast the object to the Dto of the type of that was requested: return (EmployeeDto)object; Digesting the point, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Hello @KeithNicholas! The factory would be expecting as a parameter the type of the Dto or probably an string to determine which class must be instantiated.

Comment: @Paul no, I mean, you have 20 diffrent employees, how does your factory know which of the 20 employees you want?

Comment: usually when I have dtos, my DTO has a factory method something like ```EmployeeDTO.From(employee)``` where employee is the entity class from the database ( or wherever )

Comment: @Keith Nicholas, Ok regarding to that, I am passing this as a parameter into the GetEmployeeDto() function, I did not included in my example, but there is included.

Comment: You use a design pattern to address a particular issue with your code. What problem are you trying to address here? And which pattern do you mean? The Gang of Four book has no *Factory* pattern; it has *Abstract Factory* and *Factory Method*. There are other design patterns resources than GoF, but I don't know what you mean by *Factory* pattern. Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (at least not one that makes sense to me) to decouple an implementation meant to deal with a specific type, from this type. It seems perfectly natural for a repository dealing with `EmployeeDto` type to know directly about this type.

Not sure how does your design look at a broader view, but perhaps what you are missing is a generic interface, so your client side is not much coupled? For example, something like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>();
    T Get<T>(int id);
}
```

An implication is that you would not have `GetEmployeeDto` method as in your example, but just a general `GetDto` or even `Get`. Which leads me to another hint: following DDD-related patterns, a repository should return a domain object that is ready to use, not a DTO.

This way your domain layer can just use the repository and focus on domain logic, instead of being forced to deal with conversions. As mentioned in the comments it's good to configure an automapping library to do this for you anyway. But even with an automapper, all technicalities should be hidden from the domain layer.

Comment: Hello @BartoszKP! thanks for your comments! Regarding to the topic of the DDD-Related patterns, inside the Repository I handle the Data Access Layer, so, it means that I can manage Business Domain Objects(Entities that map with Data Base tables) but, what is expecting to return my Controller is a Dto, for that reason what I am preparing is a Dto not a Business Object Model: UnitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.GetEmployeeDto()

Comment: @Paul Sure, as I said I'm not aware of your design. I think you can apply most of this to working with DTOs as well.